# Error when starting Android Studio project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

Good night, could someone please help me with this error when running the project in android studio?

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution...

follow the error below

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

Thank you and I'll be waiting

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new project and copy over the relevant files from the old one to the new one.

As stated in the error, "to fix this problem, create a new project by running flutter create -t app  and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project."

What you need to do is run the command line command `flutter create -t app ' (where  is the location of the new project. After this a new project will be created and you can move over your code, assets, and other files to the new project.

Comment: sorry for the question but i'm new to android studio and i don't know how to do what you mentioned

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow but that sounds like it's not allowed. Sorry.

Comment: ok friend, I'll try to do what you told me, I'm starting now in android studio

jaja I say if it worked

Comment: I did what you said, but my project is not opening...
is opening Flutter Demo Home Page...
do you know what it could be?

Comment: when I go to copy my old files it says that it already exists and won't let me copy

Answer (score 0):

> project/android/app/build.grade

Try adding this

```
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

after this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: I managed to remake the project with the command that the program itself indicates, the problem is that I cannot move my files from the old project to this new one, when I go to move it says that it already exists and does not replace